# find the time different between the day

Tags: python

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvNZx.png)
I have different machine running different hours that might cross over a day and I want to differentiate it on different day

Example Machine A running 8 hours from Start Date and Time 12-Aug, 9pm to 13-Aug , 5am
I cant get the correct time that 3hours from 12-Aug and 5hours from 13-Aug
Suspect that because i'm using datetime.now
how do it change the date will be same as Start date/ End date in python?

Here is my code:

```
endoftoday = datetime.now()
endoftoday = endoftoday.replace(hour=23,minute=59,second=59)

dt['Start_Date']=dt['Start_Time'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
dt['End_Date']=dt['Finish_Time'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

if (dt.['Start_Date'].str == dt['End_Date'].str):
    dt['Tested_Time_Today']= endoftoday-dt['Start_Time']
    dt['Tested_Time_NextDay']= dt['Finish_Time'] - endoftoday
```

Comment: Please provide a full working example of what you tried and what you were expecting to get. We don't know what `dt` contains or is. Your if-condition will also yield odd results if you are, as I would guess, using pandas because you compare the two str-submodules which have no connection to your data (`.str` doesn't actually convert the content to a string, but rather switches to string operations)

Comment: Thanks, i added the photo there. hope that is helps. i expecting to get another column Tested_Time_Today and Tested_Time_NextDay for those machine that different date between start and end date. I cant find any good type for my code as only str is not giving me error during compile.

Comment: @RynxYee, it is not clear to me, what your question is. Provide some example what the input is and what do you expect to get...

Comment: I have Input Start Date and End Date on that machine, i want to create a code that can come out the output that machine used time on each day.  Example Machine A running 8 hours from Start Date and Time 12-Aug, 9pm to 13-Aug ,  5am. The out put will be  Machine A   12-Aug - 3hours and 13-Aug - 5 hours

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


def get_times(args):
    start_time, end_time, start_date, end_date = args
    hours = {}
    for day in pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='d'):
        hours[day] = max(day, end_time) - max(start_time, day) + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
    return hours


df = pd.DataFrame({'Start_Time': [datetime.datetime(2021,8,21,6,2), datetime.datetime(2021,8,21,7,19)], 'Finish_Time': [datetime.datetime(2021,8,22,5,12), datetime.datetime(2021,8,21,16,50)], 'Start_Date': [datetime.date(2021,8,21), datetime.date(2021,8,21)], 'End_Date': [datetime.date(2021,8,22), datetime.date(2021,8,21)]})
df['hours'] = df.apply(get_times, axis=1)
print(df)
```

This is probably not exactly what you are looking for since I also don't really understand your question well enough. But what you get is a new column which contains in each row a dictionary with the dates as key and the hours during that day as value.

If you let us know what exactly you are after, I might be able to improve the answer.

Edit: This won't work if your time period covers more than two days. If that is necessary, the time calculation would have to slightly extended. And if you have more columns than the ones that we perform the calculation on, please change the penultimate row to `df['hours'] = df[['Start_Time', 'Finish_Time', 'Start_Date', 'End_Date']].apply(get_times, axis=1)`